# How to save data at the top of the list Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Hi it is possible in node mongoose save/insert data at the top of the list?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

here is an update request for your collection,

```
{
  $push: {
    <field>: {
       $each: [ <value> ],
       $position: 0
    }
  }
}
```